# Primefaces - ui:repeat component does not update

Tags: ajax, primefaces

I have a problem to ajax update an ui:repeat. The update is triggered from a commandButton outside the ui:repeat (see the code below). The variable *priceHour* is required to calculate the other prices (week, Monat..)

```
<h:form id="myForm">
<ui:repeat id="alvs" var="alv" value="#{myBean.allV}" >  
    <h:panelGroup rendered="#{alv.status == 'ON'}" > 
    <div class="pricing">

        <h:outputText styleClass="bold" value="#{alv.shortName}: "/>

        <p:inputText value="#{alv.priceHour}" id="hour" required="true" >                 
        <f:convertNumber pattern="#.##" type="currency" />  
        </p:inputText>   

        <p:inputText value="#{alv.priceDay}" id="day" >                
        <f:convertNumber pattern="#.##" type="currency" />
        </p:inputText>

        <p:inputText value="#{alv.priceWeek}" id="week" >                 
        <f:convertNumber pattern="#.##" type="currency" /> 
        </p:inputText> 

        <p:inputText value="#{alv.priceMonth}" id="month" >                   
        <f:convertNumber pattern="#.##" type="currency" /> 
        </p:inputText>  

    </div>
    </h:panelGroup>

    <p:messages />  

    </ui:repeat>

<p:commandButton value="Calculator" actionListener="#{myBean.priceCalc}" process="@this,alvs:hour" update="alvs" /> 

</h:form >
```

When I click the button nothing happens and the ui:repeat and the prices are not updated. What is wrong? 
  I tried also *update"myForm:alvs"*, *update":myForm:alvs"*: nothing!
 
I'm using primefaces 3.5
 
Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't think that you can update the `ui:repeat` itself, you can update the `h:form` instead.

Comment: That's exactly what I want to avoid, because there is a lot of other components and inpufields inside the same `h:form`.

Comment: So just wrap it inside a `h:panelGroup`...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`ui:repeat` is not a rendered component, so you won't see anything in HTML about it. You can't update something that is not rendered. Also the `ui:repeat` doesn't even have an `id` attribute.

You need to wrap your `ui:repeat` inside a component such as `h:panelGroup` for example like this :

```
<h:panelGroup id="alvs">
    <ui:repeat ...>
    </ui:repeat>
</h:panelGroup>
```

And update the panelgroup in your button :

```
<p:commandButton value="Calculator" actionListener="#{myBean.priceCalc}" process="@this,alvs" update="alvs" />
```

Notice that I've removed the `:hour` since you can't spectify it, each IDs will be different for each repeat.

**More info :**

- [JSF 2.0 ui:repeat](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/ui/repeat.html)

Comment: `ui:repeat` does have an id attribute! One can see it in Html code.  Anyway, your approach works. Thank you.

Comment: @codyLine You can try `<ui:repeat ...><span>test</span></ui:repeat>` and you won't see anything else than multiple `span` :)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. The proposed answers didn't work for me: the ui:repeat doesn't want to be updated by ajax, whatever I do. I used PrimeFaces data list instead and it worked like a charm.

http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/dataList.xhtml

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid I don't know the reason for it to not work, I hate when that kind of stuff happens to me working with JSF. As I workaround, you can try surrounding the `ui:repeat` with a `p:outputPanel` and then update that panel.

Comment: A `p:outputPanel` is a bit overkill since it will output bunch of HTML/CSS.

Comment: I can't `process` the `priceHour` component any more! I tried `@this`, `@this,myForm:panel:alvs:hour`, `@this,panel:alvs:hour` and `@this,alvs:hour` nothing!