# cannot find expression for component

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am learning Primefaces 6.1, and I want to update a `ui:repeat` component. According to [Alexandre's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17224365/primefaces-uirepeat-component-does-not-update), I need to wrap `ui:component` inside a component, such as `h:panelGroup`. However, when I run the project, there is an error says:

> cannot find expression for component 'blogList'

Anyone knows why? Below is part of my code.

```
 <h:form>
     <h:panelGrid columns="2" style="margin-bottom:10px" cellpadding="5" >
        <h:outputLabel value="Keyword: " for="keyword" />
        <p:inputText id="keyword" class="searchbox" value="#{viewManagedBean.keyword}"></p:inputText>

        <p:commandButton value="Search" actionListener="#{viewManagedBean.search(event)}" update="blogList"/>
     </h:panelGrid>

     <h:panelGroup id="blogList">
         <ui:repeat value="#{viewManagedBean.guestBlogs}" var="blog">
             <p:panel id="toggleable" header="#{blog.title}" footer="Created Date:#{blog.createdTime}" widgetVar="panel" style="margin-bottom:20px">
                 <h:outputText escape="false" value="#{blog.body}" style="font-weight: bold"/><hr />
             </p:panel>
         </ui:repeat>
     </h:panelGroup>
 </h:form>
```

Comment: Hi, 1 question per question please... And did you try the links provided by https://www.google.nl/search?q=cannot+find+expression+for+component+jsf?

Comment: `widgetVar="panel"` should not work if `guestBlogs.size() > 1`, as `widgetVar`must be unique (per page)

Comment: @Kukeltje yeah, I tried with :blogList, still cannot. But when I tried again in the afternoon, it works.

Comment: @jp-jee thanks for your advice, actually, I did not need this attribute. Maybe I should delete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for BalusC's answer of ["how to address ID in primefae"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8634156/how-to-find-out-client-id-of-component-for-ajax-update-render-cannot-find-compo).

I add the `id` attribute in the `h:form`:

```
<h:form id="form">
```

and modify the `update` to

```
update=":form:dataList"
```

then it works!

Comment: So it is effectively a duplicate?